# how to export keycloak users v23.0.3

Tags: keycloak

keycloak version 23.0.3
i want to export user details as a json file but the admin console ui doesn't have an option for that so can someone help me with kcadm tool

D:\keycloak-23.0.3\keycloak-23.0.3\bin> kcadm config credentials --server http://url --realm r --user@gmail.com --password xxxxx --client admin-cli

used the above command to log in but it doesn't work get the error message below,
Logging into http://url as user@gmail.com of realm master
null [Unable to find matching target resource method]

"changed URL and credentials for privacy purposes."